# gradient from gauss theorem

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I have been seeing the Gauss-Green theorem, where:

$$
\int_\Omega \nabla \cdot \vec{v} dV= \oint_{S} (\vec{v} \cdot \vec{n}) dS
$$

And the gradient theorem which states:

$$
\int_\Omega \nabla s dV= \oint_{S} (s \vec{n}) dS
$$

The derivation appears to be done by considering a constant $\vec{v}$ in the derivation such that:

$$
\int_\Omega \nabla \cdot (s \vec{v}) dV = \int_\Omega s \nabla \cdot \vec{v} + \vec{v} \cdot \nabla s dV
$$

$$
\int_\Omega \vec{v} \cdot \nabla s dV = \oint_S \vec{v} \cdot (s \vec{n}) dS
$$

As $\vec{v}$ is constant I can take it out of the integral? What is the next step here? Also, does this mean that this only applies when the vector is constant?

Comment: $v$ is not constant, otherwise the divergence would be $0$.

Comment: @Surb Noted. Can you help me derive the gradient expression from the divergence theorem?

Comment: I found this document: https://www.lehman.edu/faculty/anchordoqui/VC-4.pdf. Where the author does consider the vector quantity to be a constant.

Answer (score 0):

This is a vector valued identity, so I'll just deal with the first component. Consider the vector field $F=(s,0,0, \dots, 0)$. Then $div(F)= \partial _{x_1} s$, while $F \cdot n = s n_1$, with $n$ the normal vector to $S= \partial \Omega$.  Repeat for every component to conclude. To be more precise, for the $j$-th component you consider $(0, 0, \dots, s, \dots, 0)$ with $s$ in $j$-th position, and you repeat the argument above.

EDIT: As requested, I'll try to be more precise. The gradient theorem, as you call it, involves a vector equality. The gradient is a vector and the integral over a surface of a vector is, again, a vector. If I prove that each components of the vectors are equal, the whole equality is proves. Now, let's start from the first component. The first component reads as:

$$ \int_\Omega \partial_{x_1} s dV = \int_S s n_1 dS$$

with $n_1$ the first component of the normal unit vector to $\partial \Omega =S$. I want to use the divergence theorem to prove the above equality, and the trick is to consider the vector field $F=(s, 0, \dots, 0)$. Why? Because by definition $div(F)= \partial_{x_1} s$. So:

$$ \int_\Omega \partial_{x_1} s = \int_\Omega div(F) = \int_S (F \cdot n) dS =  \int_S s n_1 dS .$$

For the other components, it's the same just changing the definition of $F$, putting $s$ in the required position.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I did not get it. Do you know of any derivation from the Gauss-green theorem?

Comment: @Chicha what about now? Better?